# How to reopen the Google Drive icon?

Tags: catalina, google-apps

Sometimes the icon of Google Drive, on the top menu, disappears. This really annoys me also because this is happening always more frequently (and I don't want to go to the web browser and search for Google Drive, etc. I don't know how to solve this unless I restart the mac, but this is also annoying and undesirable.

So, is there a way of making that icon reappear, i.e. restart Google Drive's client on the mac, in case it dies?

Comment: I had the same issue. I found that opening the app worked fine, as @wch1zpink pointed out. Google Drive sync had so many bugs for me, like re-adding photos that I deleted and hogging resources, that I just uninstalled it after I got the news that photos was removing unlimited support. I instead switched to the web ui.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your Applications folder in Finder and double click the application "Backup and Sync from Google.app".  If that does not work, other options may need to be explored.